# How to download a .txt file from ftp server

Tags: android

I have to download a .txt format file fro my server to my android machine. But i don't know how to download a file from server which contains username as well as password to download file. Does any one help me for that. I am new to android programming.

Comment: Check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16128559/how-to-download-a-txt-file-from-ftp-server

Answer (score 1):

Look for commons net apache library - http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/. It provides a tools for work with FTP.

Code example

```
    FileOutputStream videoOut;
    File targetFile = new File("path");

    FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
    try {
        ftpClient.connect("your.ftp.address", 21);
        ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        ftpClient.login("login", "password");

        ftpClient.setFileType(FTPClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);// Used for video
        targetFile.createNewFile();
        videoOut = new FileOutputStream(targetFile);
        boolean result=ftpClient.retrieveFile("/" + "filename-to-download", videoOut);

        ftpClient.disconnect();
        videoOut.close();    

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: You can use FTPClient.ASCII_FILE_TYPE. For understanding differencies read http://www.unix.com/answers-frequently-asked-questions/13574-text-files-ascii-files-binary-files-ftp-transfers.html